# BeautifulSoup, findAll('table') returns all tables but also the text between them

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-table

I am trying to isolate part of a webpage, unfortunately it isn't contained within anything that I can pull out.

The closest I can get is to get the entire body of the webpage and then try to remove the tables (which are the only parts I don't want).

[Example Page](http://www.hpfandom.net/eff/viewstory.php?sid=46010&i=1)

The code I am using:

```
storyText = soup.body
toRemove = storyText.findAll('table')
for each in toRemove:
    print each
```

The problem at the moment is that the toRemove line returns the tables *and* the text contained between them though not *in* them.

So I get:

```
<body>
<table>
    table stuff
</table>
    Text, not in tags </br> #This is what I want.
<table>
    table stuff
</table
</body>
```

I have worked around my problem by doing the following:

```
# Isolate body
findBody = soup.body
new = str(findBody)
# Section off the text from the tables before it.
sec = new.split('</table>')
# Select story area
newStory = sec[3]
# Section off the text from the tables after it.
newSec = newStory.split('<table')
# Select the story area, this the area that we want.
story = newSec[0]
```

I am still looking for an answer as it seems there should be a far cleaner way to do this.

Comment: so on the example page given you are trying to get all the text?

Comment: From It Begins onwards, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on my Mac.
Which version did you use? I used Beautiful Soup 4.

(Beautiful Soup 3 is not recommended. Because, It is no longer being developed. http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

contents = '''<body>
<table>
     table stuff1
</table>
     Text, not in tags </br> #This is what I want.
<table>
     table stuff2
</table>
</body>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(contents)

storyText = soup.body
toRemove = storyText.findAll('table')
for each in toRemove:
    print each
    each.extract()

print '----result-------------'
print soup
```

The following results will come out.

```
<table>
    table stuff1
</table>
<table>
    table stuff2
</table>
----result-------------
<body>

    Text, not in tags  #This is what I want.

</body>
```

Comment: I'm using BS4, I've tried using the code that works for you but it doesn't do what I need, it removes both the tables *and* the text I want from the soup.

Comment: Hmm, It could be caused by the default HTML parser.
Change the 13th line of my code as followed:
`
    soup = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html5lib')
`
You might install html5lib with one of these commands:

$ apt-get install python-html5lib

$ easy_install html5lib

$ pip install html5lib